# -bash: createdb: command not found

Tags: django, macos, postgresql

I'm using a Mac and I already have installed PostgreSQL in my computer using the dmg provided by PostgreSQL (and not by Postgres.app).

I have installed it because I will go to use it with Django, and for to get the correct functionality with the framework, I had to do the next commands:

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/:"$PATH”
sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib 
sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib

$ sudo mv /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib.old  
$ sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/lib
```

Then I executed the command:

./manage.py migrate

Getting at the terminal a message like this:

[image]

And knowing that I needed to create a user "erikb" in PostgreSQL.

I can enter in terminal the command:

```
sudo su - postgres
```

To enter to PostgreSQL, but when I wanted to create a DB o a new user, it sent me the next error: `-bash: createuser: command not found`

[image]

Does anyone know which could be the problem?

Regards.

Comment: And if I execute the command `which createdb`, to know where was installed this function, it doesnt return me anything.

Answer (score 3):

You set the `PATH` variable in your user account, and then you su'd to a *different user*. That user does not inherit your environment, including your path.

You need to set the environment for that user, or else use the full path to the `createdb` command.

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/:$PATH
createdb erikb
```